# Null-conditional operator in Expression.PropertyOrField

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I'm trying to build a function that will sort a list of `T` by specified field (as a `string` name of the field), including fields in nested objects. I can create expression like this: `l.FooObject.Name`, but I don't know how to create an expression like this: `l.FooObject?.Name` or at least like this `(l.FooObject == null) ? default : l.FooObject.Name`

This is my function:

```
public static List<T> Sort(List<T> sourceList, string sortBy)
{
    var propertyNames = sortBy.Split('.');
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    Expression propertyAccess = parameter;
    foreach (var propertyName in propertyNames)
    {
        propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(propertyAccess, propertyName);
    }

    var propertyValue = Expression.Convert(propertyAccess, typeof(object));
    var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propertyValue, parameter);

    var query = sourceList.AsQueryable();
    query = query.OrderBy(sortExpression);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

The problem is this line: `propertyAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(propertyAccess, propertyName);`

The expression created by this function will throw `System.NullReferenceException` if Nested object is null. For example having these two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Foo? FooObject { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to sort `List<Bar>` by *"FooObject.Name"* it will throw an exception if there is at least one `Bar` object with null `FooObject`. It will build expression like this `l.FooObject.Name`. I need `l.FooObject?.Name`

Thanks for help!

Comment: Expression.Condition(nullcheck, notnullpathexpressionprollyyourcurrentexpression, nullpathexpressionprollyconstnullifexpectedtype)